# Open a csv file from hard disk without giving location of csv file

Tags: vba, excel

How to open a csv file from hard disk using VBA without giving the specific location of the file.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in your question and describe what you have tried?  This is very vague.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know where it is and the macro needs to find it, or you know where it is but don't want the user to have to type the full path?

Comment: i have a csv file in my hard disk , i want to open it using macro, without giving the specific location of that csv file.

Comment: just opening a csv file without giving specific path using macro.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?  You'll need to write code to search through your hard drive for the file, which will involve some kind of recursion and using Dir().

Comment: i need that code to search file in my hard drive and open it

Comment: The answer you have accepted does not run a search, it allows the user to browse for a `csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub GetCSV()

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    'You can get fancier with the "filter" argument, see the internet for more info
    sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.csv,*.csv")

    'False means they clicked cancel
    If sFile <> "False" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
        'do stuff
        wb.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this meets the actual intent of the question as clarified - well to some degree - by *I need that code to search file in my hard drive and open it*

Comment: I think it's just a language thing.  Buy 'search' he meant a human search (navigating the file structure through a file open dialog) not code that performs a search.